# Does SQL LIKE iterate every row of table

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I am just curious that if i have billions of rows in my `SQL` database's `table` in which one `field` is `Username` and i have to search names starting from letter `G` and data in db is unsorted so is `LIKE` statment iterate every row?? 
And if i sort data in my table and is it possible to use something like `Binary Search` to reduce time of searching if yes then how to do it? or after sorting i have to still stuck with `LIKE`?

Comment: Always check MySQL's execution plan with `EXPLAIN SELECT....` on the desired query. If `username` is indexed, and you are trying to match the _start_ of the string, MySQL may be able to use that index. It won't be able to use the index if you use wildcards on both sides `WHERE Username LIKE '%middle%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
where username like 'G%'
```

and there is no index, then MySQL will scan every row.

There is really no concept in SQL of "sorted tables".  There is a more powerful concept of indexes.  If you have an index where `username` is the first (or only key), then MySQL would generally use the index for this type of query.  It can do this because the `like` pattern starts with a constant.

The following would *not* use an index:

```
where username like '%G'
where username like '%G%'
where left(username, 1) = 'G'
```